# How to write a generic rollback or halt in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, cancellation

These examples are going to be super simplified but hopefully you get the gist.

Say I have a function as so, which runs a series of tasks and can take a long time:

```js
async function doSomeStuff() {
  await aLongTask();
  await anotherBigOldTask();
  await bigNestedTaskThatTakesForever();
  return Promise.resolve('Done');
}
```

Now I have a chokidar watch which looks for file changes and runs said function:

```js
const watcher = chokidar.watch(watchURLs, {
  ignored: /\.git/,
  ignoreInitial: true,
  persistent: true,
  ignorePermissionErrors: true,
  atomic: 500,
});
watcher.on('all', async (event, filePath) => {
  await doSomeStuff();
});
```

The issue is that when the files are changed many times whilst `doSomeStuff()` is running, it tries to run the build multiple times. This causes a whole wealth of errors, which I've crudely fixed with a timeout lock:

```js
if (!locked) {
  await doSomeStuff().finally(() => {
    locked = false;
    info('Waiting for file changes in', ...watchURLs);
  });
}
else {
  debug('Attempting to trigger a locked build');
}
locked = true;
clearTimeout(lockTimeout);
lockTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
  locked = false;
  debug('Unlocked due to timeout');
}, 10000);
```

This stops stuff from *completely* imploding, but it means that everything will always be out of date. It's only when saving a file after the lock grace period is over that it will be picked up. And if a load of files are saved, it could build with just half of the updated ones included.

So, how can the `doSomeStuff()` function be completely cancelled/halted/rolled-back immediately before a new build is triggered? I don't want to do something where I'm setting a variable that causes `doSomeStuff()` to return that I wrap around every task, because that's not immediate, and doesn't work for any chuggy functions nested inside. It's almost as if I want to throw an error *into* a function, rather than that function controlling what to throw for itself.

Can anyone think of a way of immediately forcing a function to stop executing without killing the whole script (a la `process.exit()`)? Or if there's just a simple way of doing this kind of thing? TIA.

Comment: Why not just run your builds to completion, but never concurrently?

Comment: @Bergi That's what is happening already. If you mean queuing them, it would of course end up building up beyond control pretty quickly. I guess if builds B and C were triggered during build A, it could wait for A to complete and then run C. But it would mean having to wait for two builds to complete. State isn't really important as it either trashes at the start of a build or does a load of checks throughout, so the equivalent of ctrl+c and then rerunning is perfectly fine

Comment: Yes, I mean queuing at most one at a time. Your current code has this weird grace period that doesn't seem to work at all. Yes, that would mean waiting for A and C, but on the plus side you'd always have complete build results and not a swoop of started builds that never finished.

Comment: My current code unlocks at the end of the build, the timeout is just in case for some reason the build doesn't finish, it's a failsafe. But yeah it's definitely a fudgy way of doing things, I just needed it to not break, and then find a better solution later

Comment: Ah right, 10s are failsafe only. What I'm missing is just a flag for repeat - if there was a watcher event while it was locked, another build should be started when the lock is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing in an error actually sounds good, that can be done quite elgantly:

```
 const cancellable = fn => (...args) => {
  let cancel = false;
  const breakpoint = () => {
    if(cancel) throw new Error("Cancelation");
  };

  return {
    result: fn(breakpoint, ...args).catch(console.log),
    stop() { cancel = true; },
  };
};
```

That can be used as:

```
const doSomeStuff = cancellable(async function doSomeStuff(breakpoint) {
  await aLongTask();
  breakpoint();
  await anotherBigOldTask();
  breakpoint();
  await bigNestedTaskThatTakesForever();
  return "Done";
 });

 let task = doSomeStuff();
 task.stop();
```

Comment: But what about if it's re-called when `aLongTask ` is in the middle of doing its thing? It'd have to wait until after it's done and by that time the multiple functions running simultaneously could still cause havok...? (Also I mentioned I'd prefer to avoid that type of pattern: `> I don't want to do something where I'm setting a variable that causes doSomeStuff() to return that I wrap around every task`)

Comment: @matt then you'd have to start a separate thread and terminate that.

Comment: Ohhh... interesting. So as in do a `child_process.fork()`? Or some other suggestion? Forking and multithreading isn't really my forté. But yeah, I hadn't thought about that. Actually a great idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are looking for is not possible. There is no "task" abstraction that implicitly wraps something, and you cannot interrupt arbitrary functions. They need to explicitly opt into being cancellable (e.g. by checking a `breakpoint` that is passed to them, like in Jonas' answer). You can do that using a child process which you can kill, but that might leave inconsistent state behind.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

**Promise Cancellation** This *does* exist. You need a polyfill to add support for `.cancel` which when called will cancel the Promise execution. You can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@benlesh/promise-cancellation-is-dead-long-live-promise-cancellation-c6601f1f5082). Once you install a polyfill, your promise will have a `.cancel` so you can have:

```
const doSomeStuff = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        ...
    })
}

let prmise = null;
const watcher = chokidar.watch(watchURLs, {
  ignored: /\.git/,
  ignoreInitial: true,
  persistent: true,
  ignorePermissionErrors: true,
  atomic: 500,
});
watcher.on('all', (event, filePath) => {
  promise = doSomeStuff();
});
watcher.on('change', () => {
  promise && promise.cancel()
});
```

**Rollbar** This *does not* exist. You'd have to implement this yourself. Maybe take a snapshot of the state at the very beginning of `doSomeStuff` and then if `.cancel` was called, update the state to match the beginning state. But a "rollback" is not a predefined thing that can have native support, unlike databases where a rollback has a pretty good definition.